# Is it possible to know where a jquery draggable element will revert to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the color of my draggable if it is reverting to a certain location. In this example, the red box changes to blue when you drag it to the green boxes on the right. I've set it so when you drag a box on top of another one, it reverts to where it was. But if the box is reverting to the container on the left, I want it to change back to red, which it does if you drag it manually there. I could also make it so if a box is in the left container it is always red, but I don't know how to do that. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[Fiddle!!!](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/xE9Pe/3/)

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="box">
    <div class="peg">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="space">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="peg">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div id="game">
    <ul class="row">
        <li class="hole">&nbsp;</li>
        <li class="hole">&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#game {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 135px;
    background: wheat;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.row {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: olive;
}

.hole {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    float: left;
    background-color: aqua;
    opacity: 0.3;
    margin-left: 6px;
}

#box {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    top: 15px;
    width: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: wheat;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.peg {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1;
}
.space {
    height: 15px;
    width: 75px;
}

.top {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    z-index: 1;
}
​
```

Javascript:

```
$('.peg' ).draggable({
    snap: ".hole", 
    snapMode: "inner", 
    snapTolerance: 40, 
    //scope: "zappa",
    //revert: 'invalid',
    stop: function(){
        $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
    },
    //helper: "clone"
});    

$('.peg').droppable({
    tolerance: 'fit'
});

$('.peg').droppable({
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function(event,ui){
        ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
    }
});

$('.hole').droppable({
     drop: function(e,ui) {
          $(ui.draggable).removeClass('peg').addClass('top');
     },
     //scope: "zappa"
});

$('#box').droppable({
     drop: function(e,ui) {
          $(ui.draggable).removeClass('top').addClass('peg');
     },
     //scope: "zappa"
});
​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead you can create a control class for the `$('.hole').droppable(...)` to actually prevent other boxes to change at all if a box is already in the hole.

```
 $('.hole').droppable({
   drop: function(e,ui) {
     //Check the hole control class
     if(!$(this).hasClass('full')){

         //its empty so change the class of the box
         $(ui.draggable).removeClass('peg').addClass('top');

         //if you want to prevent the box in the hole from being draggable again uncomment next line
         //$(ui.draggable).unbind('mousedown');

         //put the hole control class
         $(this).addClass('full')
     }else{
         //its full
     }                   
   },
   out: function(){ 
        //if the item can go out of the hole then

        //remove the hole control class
        $(this).removeClass('full')
   }

 });
```

**Update**

If you need to control what happens when you get a box out of the hole, then add the `out` function to the droppable, i updated the link and the code.

[solution](http://jsfiddle.net/FHF8N/20/)

Comment: After a few movements back and forth and on top of each other, the boxes stop changing colors and stay red...

Comment: ok, so you will want to keep the dragging after the box have reached the hole?

Comment: @EH_warch yep! whatever you did fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

We can also solve above issue as given below:

Alternate way of jQuery:

```
$('.peg').draggable({
    snap: ".hole",
    snapMode: "inner",
    snapTolerance: 40,
    stop: function() {
        $(this).draggable('option', 'revert', 'invalid');
    }
});

$('.peg').droppable({
    tolerance: 'fit',
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', true);
    }
});

$('.hole').droppable({
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).switchClass('peg', 'top');
    },
});

$('#box').droppable({
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).switchClass('top', 'peg');
    },
});
```

You can find complete solution on codebins, so click on http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpbs

Comment: Not sure how is this different from the problem, in your solution if another box is putted in the same hole then the box turns blue instead of remaining red.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't solve the problem, when the boxes revert to the left, they aren't to red.